# How to quickly anonymize the logs I paste?

Tags: php, debugging, github, issue-tracking

Okay, so I am excessively posting logs and other debug ouput at GitHub, StackOverflow, our internal issues tracker and so on for the purpose of debugging or giving examples. Usually I copy the the log, use a search and replace to replace domain names, my home directory or IP addresses.

I guess others are doing the same - so what are your solutions to this problems? Please share.

Comment: Did you intend to post this on Meta?

Comment: I did not, while it might good an idea - but I am basically searching for a programmatic solution to my problem. So it fits here as well.

Comment: So what you want is a solution to replace every occurrence of some pattern (IP, domain, ...) with generic values? Without a language tag this is too broad, and with one it has probably been asked before.

Comment: Yes. An extensible solution would be the best. I am mostly interested in PHP error / exception dumps

Comment: As this question lacks a language tag it is too broad. If it did have a language tag, it would very probably have a duplicate somewhere. As such this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please add details (patterns to detect, language, ...) to narrow down your question.